# Get the matching condition in the SELECT list

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, full-text-search, string-searching

Let's say my full text search query is below:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
SELECT Name  
FROM Production.Product  
WHERE CONTAINS(Name, '"chain*" OR "full*"');  
GO
```

I need one more column that shows which condition was matched in the `CONTAINS` clause.

```
SELECT Name ,Matched_condition 
FROM Production.Product  
WHERE CONTAINS(Name, '"chain*" OR "full*"');
```

```
+---------------------+-------------------+
| name                | matched_condition |
+---------------------+-------------------+
| chain smokers       | chain             |
+---------------------+-------------------+
| full throttle       | full              |
+---------------------+-------------------+
| chain full of smoke | chain,full        |
+---------------------+-------------------+
```

What should I use to get the new column (`matched_condition`)?

I have a list of conditions that includes 200 words.

Answer (score 2):

Possible realization. Fulltext search replaced with common LIKE substring search.

Source table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (val VARCHAR(16));

INSERT INTO test VALUES
('1 chaining'),
('2 fullfill'),
('3 full chain'),
('4 no pattern');
```

Patterns table (can be temporary or table-type variable):

```
CREATE TABLE patterns (pattern VARCHAR(8));

INSERT INTO patterns VALUES
('%chain%'),
('%full%');
```

The query:

```
SELECT test.val, STUFF( ( SELECT ',' + pattern
                          FROM ( SELECT test.val, patterns.pattern
                                 FROM patterns
                                 WHERE test.val LIKE patterns.pattern
                               ) tmp
                          FOR XML PATH('') 
                        ), 1, 1,'' 
                      ) matched_patterns
FROM test;
```

Query result:

```
    val      | matched_patterns 
------------ | ---------------- 
1 chaining   | %chain%          
2 fullfill   | %full%           
3 full chain | %chain%,%full%   
4 no pattern |
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9d240cb0802655a09084c1a7de0e3f98)

Answer (score 0):

[mcnets](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/110455/mcnets): Can't you use:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CONTAINS(Name, '"chain*") THEN 'chain' ELSE 'full' END
```

---

[akina](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/150107/akina):

```
CASE
    WHEN CONTAINS(Name, '"chain*") AND NOT CONTAINS(Name, '"full*") THEN '"chain"'
    WHEN CONTAINS(Name, '"full*") AND NOT CONTAINS(Name, '"chain*") THEN '"full"'
    ELSE 'both chain and full'
END
```

looks more informative.